# How can I remove files that were changed and then reverted on a branch from a merge

Tags: merge, perforce

I have a branch in Perforce on which I have checked in changes to several thousand files, and then later backed out the changes to approximately half of those files - so the latest revision of some of the files on the branch is unchanged from the baseline, but there are intermediate revisions with changes.

In many cases there have also been out-merges from mainline in the meantime, so the history is a bit more complicated, but the eventual result is that there are no content changes left to merge back to mainline.

I now want to merge that branch to mainline, but I don't want to check in "null" changes to the files that in the end were not modified on the branch.

Normally one can avoid checking in unchanged files with "Revert unchanged files" in p4v, but in this case it won't revert the files, because it believes that the file needs to be checked in to update the integration record. The help for `p4 revert` confirms this:

> The -a flag  reverts only files that are open for edit or integrate
>   and are unchanged or missing. **Files with pending integration records
>   are left open.** The file arguments are optional when -a is specified.

Is there any way I can avoid checking these files in without going through them one by one? I'm happy to do whatever is necessary on the branch, and I'm not too worried about it it causes future merges *to* the branch as I will be abandoning it soon after this merge.

Comment: When you reverted the changes, do you mean that you actually checked in the changes and then backed them out and checked in again?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Many would consider it worthwhile to check in these otherwise-null changes, because they are not actually null. They are a record of intermediate activity in the development branch which, although in the end contributed no changes to the content of these files, still represented valid intermediate states of the files, and thus are worth recording in the integration history to indicate that you have analyzed the merges and determined that the final result is the desired one. Future code historians will find this history valuable.

Comment: Agreed for some cases, but in this situation they simply represent an error and there's no point in cluttering up mainline. It would give the mistaken impression that the work on the branch had been relevant to these particular files, and it wasn't. The situation is most akin to a locally developed commit with mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to revert files that have no differing content (i.e., where the only change is to update the integration record) you can do something like this batch file (you'll need to translate to a shell script if running on Linux):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=# " %%x in ('p4 diff -Od //depot/path/you/care/about/... 2^>nul ^| findstr /c:"//depot"') do (
    p4 revert %%x
)
```

We use something similar where I work because we have a number of files that are marked +l and if we're doing an integration that takes a while to validate, the people that need to work on those files are locked out.

Comment: What's `-Od` supposed to do? I can't find it in my version of p4 (2013.1) or documented in other versions.

Comment: In the end I decided that it was easier to just live with the spurious merge commits rather than do this on each merge (I'm gradually merging bits of the branch selectively so it would have been quite disruptive), but I think this would have been the best solution if I'd decided it was worth the pain.

Comment: `The -Od flag limits output to files that differ.` in 2013.2, at least.  I don't know when that was added.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the changes that got reverted were actually checked into the branch, and then backed out, my suggestion would be to (using **extreme** caution) obliterate the two revisions of the files that got reverted (the initial change, and the change that put it back to the initial state). I *think* that should prevent them from getting merged back into the mainline.

I would strongly suggest testing this out on a test branch before trying it on your live branch.

Comment: Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately!) I'm not an administrator so this isn't an option unless I'm desperate.

Comment: Also, there've been out-merges (I just edited the question a bit more to mention those), so I think I'd have to obliterate the entire history on the branch and then redo those out-merges. I guess that would be doable if obliterate were an option in the first place.